# How to lock a file until next reboot?

Tags: delphi, file, file-io, restart

On delphi I found that I can lock a file like this:

```
aHandle     := CreateFile(PChar(aFileName),GENERIC_READ, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0); // get the handle of the file
aFileSize   := GetFileSize(aHandle,nil); //get the file size for use in the  lockfile function
Win32Check(LockFile(aHandle,0,0,aFileSize,0)); //lock the file
```

But is there a way to keep the file locked until the next reboot *without having the app running until then*?

Comment: I think some background of what you are trying to accomplish might help. Often people ask how to do something, when they really should be looking at a higher level approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I'd be interested in the use case for this!

You may just need to keep the application running, if you really want to keep the file locked.

However, it may be better to step back to the actual *problem* you're trying to solve rather than positing a *solution.* People who assume the solution must take a specific form generally disadvantage themselves by not considering all options.

If your intent is to stop people from modifying the file, it's probably better to use permissions to do it, since this will work regardless of whether programs have the file locked at any given time.

However, if you *must* do it this way and you want to prevent people killing your application to unlock the file, you can use the [RobinHood/FriarTuck method](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/staff/magi/personal/humour/Computer_Folklore/Robin%20Hood%20And%20Friar%20Tuck.html) to make it more "secure".

Have one program (Robin) lock the file and also start a second program (Tuck). If at any time Tuck exits, have Robin restart it immediately.

Similarly, Tuck will track the status of Robin, and restart it immediately should it exit.

That's by no means *totally* secure but it seriously reduces the window in which the file can be modified, as Robin and Tuck protect each other.

It's also *evil,* so you may want to be sure you want this functionality before you unleash it.